# Android KeyEvents from Service API22

Tags: java, android, service, background-process

Asking in the name of a friend because I already have an account with rep.

*"I have a small project going on that is supposed to activate my phone's flashlight when I press the volume up button and disable it when I press the volume down button. This is so I can easily access the flashlight even when wearing gloves. My problem here is that the app should be running as a service in the background and work when the screen is turned off and that is not possible... or so it seems."*

What we have tried:

- Background Activity
- Media Session
- Compiling SDL C++ and polling Keys from there
- Broadcast Reciever

But none of these worked.

Here is the current version of the service file:

```
//imports
public class FlashService extends Service {

public static final String BROADCAST = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON";
private static final String TAG = "OutdoorFlashlightService";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    Log.w(TAG, "Service started!");

    MediaSession _mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), TAG);

    if (_mediaSession == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "initMediaSession: _mediaSession = null");
        return;
    }

    Token _mediaSessionToken = _mediaSession.getSessionToken();

    _mediaSession.setCallback(new Callback() {
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent called: " + mediaButtonIntent);
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
        }

        public void onPause() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause called (media button pressed)");
            super.onPause();
        }

        public void onPlay() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPlay called (media button pressed)");
            super.onPlay();
        }

        public void onStop() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStop called (media button pressed)");
            super.onStop();
        }
    });

    _mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder().setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)
            .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0).build();

    _mediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);

    _mediaSession.setActive(true);
}
}
```

Here is the failed attempt at a BroadcastReciever, that never actually recieved anything:

```
package de.platzhirsch.outdoorflashlight;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Camera cam;
    private boolean lighting = false;

    public MyBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
        Log.w("", "Receiver registered!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("", "Got msg!");

        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        KeyEvent event = null;
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        }
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }

        Log.w("", "triggered...");

        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
        int action = event.getAction();
        long eventtime = event.getEventTime();

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters;
            if (cam == null) {
                cam = Camera.open();
            }
            switch (keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (!lighting) {
                    parameters = cam.getParameters();
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(parameters);
                    cam.startPreview();
                    lighting = true;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (lighting) {
                    parameters = cam.getParameters();
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(parameters);
                    cam.stopPreview();
                    cam.release();
                    cam = null;
                    lighting = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What we are looking for is really just a way to get the Volume KeyEvents to the service

*Note: The app is only intended to run on my friend's device so if all else fails a dirty device specific solution with Hardware IDs will suffice*

Comment: Why don't you listen for media button broadcast?

Comment: @7383 I added our failed attempt at a broadcast reciever...